# What is the difference between supply voltage (total bipolar supplies) and total supply voltage in an op-amp datasheet?

Tags: operational-amplifier, datasheet, maximum-ratings

There is something that I do not understand from this [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa810.pdf). Here are the "Absolute Maximum Ratings":

[image]

So suppose it is supplied by a 15 V and a -5 V. It means Vs = 15V - (-5V) = 20 V

Then it says in the recommended operating conditions:

[image]

That seems to exceed the absolute maximum rating.

Also:

[image]

What did I not understand?

What is strange is that on two boards over two boards, the op-amps are gone. Coincidence?

Comment: It's probably a typo since if Vs were the sum of both rails then the +/- couldn't be right (no way the opamp is ok with a negative V+ and a positive V-). Most likely they mean each rail is limited to 14v and the total is 28v.

Comment: So you think it could not work at a postive supply of 15V ?

Comment: It would, because op-amps generally don't care in which direction (no common or ground supply pin), only about their total voltage between the positive and negative supply pins. See my updated answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The op-amp has no GND pin**. All it sees is Vs- and Vs+, and the difference between them is what is limited.

Comment: Do you think that it could work with a supply of 15V and a supply of -5V as the datasheet mentions +14 and minus -14V ?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely fine with +15/-5 (total supply 20V). Input and output ranges, of course, are going to be approximately the same wrt ground (-5V ~ +15V) since it's a RRIO op-amp.

Answer (score 2):

±14 V just means 28 V.

Putting a ± value into the MAX column is quite misleading. The author of the datasheet tried to rescue it by writing "bipolar" into the description, but your question shows that he did not succeed.

Comment: Do you think that it could work with a supply of 15V and a supply of -5V as the datasheet mentions +14 and minus -14V ?

Comment: It does not matter how you label your voltages. The chip only sees a voltage of 20 V between its supply pins.

Comment: I am surprised because the 2 op amps that I tested are dead. So it would not be the reason ?

Comment: The unsymmetrical 20 V supply cannot damage your opamps. The problem is elsewhere. You should ask a question about your circuit (include the schematic).

Comment: Ok thank you :)

Comment: @Jess - In your schematic, you should definitely include your op-amp's model number (if different from the one you asked about), just so that we can check its specs. You may have exceeded one of its Absolute Maximum Ratings limits which would damage or destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolute maximum ratings** give the maximum values up to which a device will not be destroyed, and above them there is no guarantee it will not go up in smoke. 
In this case, the ±14V means absolute safe maximum voltage between pins V+ and V- (also marked as Vcc and Vee, as well as Vdd and Vss, respectively) is 28V.

**Recommended operating conditions** is a range of values (voltages in this case) which is recommended to stay within and not exceed during device's operation. 
In this case that's up to 27V or ±13.5V, so I don't know where do you see a discrepancy.

The thing that seems to be confusing you is why do they say "±14V" when it doesn't matter whether VS+ is at +14V while VS- is at -14V, or whether the VS+ is at +28V while VS- is at 0V. 
The reason is because in amplifier circuits there is usually both a positive and a negative signal voltage "swing", so the power supplies provide equally positive and negative voltages with 0V or ground in the middle, but the 0V supply pin is not there in the op-amp; 0V is used to reference the input and output to. 
When you connect a differential signal to an op-amp, it goes between the two of its inputs. If you connect a single-ended signal, its ground or zero point is connected to the 0V supply rail, while one of the op-amp inputs is referenced/connected to 0V. 
When the single-ended input is zero, the output should also be zero or same as the referenced zero or ground at input. 
When the differential input is zero, the output should be a DC voltage at the midpoint between the positive and negative supply rails; i.e. VS+ at +10V and VS- at -5V will give +2.5V on the output.

The one voltage limit which you seem to have ignored is the INPUT voltage, that is the voltage on the input pins: 
V<sub>IN</sub> (input voltage) = Min. V<sub>S–</sub> – 0.5; Max. V<sub>S+</sub> +0.5V 
This is the **common mode** voltage, which means the input voltage range allowed when the two inputs are tied together (0 volts between them). As you can see, this op-amp's inputs can go from 0.5V below the negative supply voltage on the VS- pin to 0.5V above the positive supply voltage on the VS+ pin. 
HOWEVER, the second requirement is the **differential** input voltage limit, which in this case is ±7V, meaning the maximum allowed voltage difference between the inverting (negative or VIN-) and non-inverting (positive or VIN+) is 7V in either direction or of either polarity between the input pins. 
So, both of those limits have to be observed at the same time, and crossing them will lead to damaged op-amp which either does not function properly or at all.

As you can see, you need to pay attention to details when reading datasheets, otherwise you run into problems and get headaches without knowing why.